# adding '1' to LOGIC_VECTOR in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to add '1' to an N-Length STD_LOGIC_VECTOR in VHDL

This is the very first time I'm using VHDL so I'm not at all sure how to add this 1 without bulding a Full-Adder which seems kinda of redundent

We are not allowed to use any more liberaries then then one in the code.

```
    LIBRARY IEEE ;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


ENTITY cnt IS

 GENERIC (n: natural :=3);

 PORT( clk: IN  std_logic;      -- clock
   rst: IN  std_logic;      -- reset
   cntNum: IN  std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0); -- # of counting cycles
   cntOut: OUT std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0) -- count result
 );
END cnt;


architecture CntBhvArc OF cnt IS

    signal counta : std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0);

begin

 process (clk, rst)

 begin

     if rst='1' then

         counta<="0";

     elsif (clk'event) and (clk='0') then

         counta<= counta+'1';

     end if;

 cntOut<=counta;

 end process;

END CntBhvArc
```

Also... can anyone point to a VHDL totrial for someone who has very little experince in programing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should not use library `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL`

This library is deprecated (see [VHDL FAQ](http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/doc/faq/FAQ1.html#4.11)); use `ieee.numeric_std.all` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last point - don't think of it as programming.  HDL stands for "hardware description language".  You're describing hardware, always keep it in mind when writing your code :)

I've also written at length [about not using STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED, but using NUMERIC_STD instead](http://www.parallelpoints.com/node/3).  If this is homework and you're being taught to use STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED, then I despair of the educational establishments.  It's been years since that made sense.

VHDL is strongly-typed, so if count is representing a number (and with a name like that, it better had be :), use either a `signed` or `unsigned` vector, or an `integer`.  Integers don't wrap around in simulation unless you make them (if you add 1 to them when they are at their max value, the simulator will terminate).  The vector types do.  Sometimes you want one behaviour, sometimes the other.

Finally, I just noted this:

```
elsif (clk'event) and (clk='0') then
```

which is better written as:

```
elsif falling_edge(clk) then
```

again, this has been so for about a decade or two.  Were you intending to use the falling edge - rising edge is more usual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the std_logic_vector to an unsigned value so you can add one, then cast it back so you can assign it to your output.

This looks like a homework assignment, so I'll leave you to figure out exactly how to do the implementation.